# How to use 十分. Differences from ずいぶん、けっこう

Tags: word-choice

while studying japanese grammar I bumped into this expression that I've quite understood, but it isn't clear to me enough yet. It's 十分 (じゅうぶん).

These are the phrases in which I've found it:

> 今日の授業は午後からなので、今から行けば十分間に合う。
>
> この冷蔵庫は中古品だけど、まだ十分使える。
>
> 江戸東京博物館は歴史を知らない人でも十分楽しめるということですよ。
>
> いいえ、もうけっこうです。十分いただきます。

It's clear that its meaning is "enough"/"plenty" (in the last case), but as it is proposed with other two words, that is けっこう and ずいぶん, I got confused about its use. When is it better to use 十分 instead of the others?

Comment: 「いいえ、もうけっこうです。十分いただきます。」<- 「十分いただきま**した** 」ではありませんか。

Comment: Don't know why my book writes -ます and not -ました, as for me too seems more correct the past form...

Answer (score 11):

1. ずいぶん is more than enough. Such as ずいぶんと散らかした meaning it is a mess.
2. 十分 is satisfactory, fulfilled. Such as 十分使える meaning it is usable and satisfactory performance.
3. 結構 is close to good enough, but imply not that fulfilled as 十分. It could imply that "you cannot complain considering the condition or situation" or more than you can expect or expected. For example, if someone performed more than you expected, then say, "彼にしては結構頑張った" and would not say 十分がんばった.

Example

1. その映画でずいぶん楽しんだ
   I got more than enough fun from the movie. It was really fun. More than expected or should expect.
2. その映画で十分楽しんだ
   I got enough fun. I am happy, but no so enough as ずいぶん
3. その映画で結構楽しんだ
   I got good fun. Close to 十分 but a bit less than that.

Comment: So, these three adverbs mean the same thing but at different levels...you've been very helpful, thank you so much!